# Input with autofocus property on Android browsers

Tags: android, html, responsive, html-input, autofocus

When using

```
<input type='text' autofocus>
```

the user can directly start typing after loading the page on a computer browser, without any other click.

On Chrome Android, the `input` receives indeed the focus on load, but the keyboard is not opened, then all the point of `autofocus` is lost.

How to make it work correctly on Android?

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type='text' onload='this.click();' autofocus >
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not work. The `input` has focus, but the keyboard is not opened on Chrome Android.

Comment: do you have js active when you instanciated the webview ?

Comment: Yes, JS is always enabled in my browser, I never disabled it.